# Null response in PHP AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a working login script on another site that loads a PHP script via AJAX. I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a null response when it should either be simply false or an array of values.

When I manually put the values into the php script (hard coded) it working. I can see in the console that the variables are being sent from the form. However, nothing is being returned. Can anyone spot what I am missing?

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Login PHP

```
<?php 
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

require_once("DB.php");
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$login' AND passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
$output = "true";
     while(list($member_id, $firstname, $lastname, $login, $passwd, $City, $State, $bday, $approved, $organization, $school, $trainingdate, $Subscriber, $wscoordinator, $Position, $subdate, $enddate, $notice, $book, $trial)  = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
echo json_encode(array('memberid' => $member_id, 'firstname' => $firstname, lastname => $lastname, approved => $approved, subscriber => $Subscriber, position => $Position, school => $school, login => $login, book =>$book, ws => $wscoordinator, trial => $trial, enddate => $enddate));
}
} else {
$output = "false";
echo json_encode($output);
}


?>
```

AJAX, using jQuery.

```
$('#loginForm #loginButton').click(function(){
        var $form = $('#loginForm'),
    $inputs = $form.find("input"),
    serializedData = $form.serialize();
    var login = $('#login').text('');
    var password = $('#password').text('');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Scripts/php/login.php',
      data: serializedData,
      success: function(response){
        console.log("Response: "+response);
        if(response != "false") 
        {
        //window.location.href='toolstart.html';
        $.cookie('lastname', response.lastname, { expires: 365, path: '/' });
        } else {
        alert("Your email and password combination did not match.");
        }

        },      
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

(Yes, I know I need to move from MD5; just haven't gotten there yet.)

Comment: Load up the PHP page manually in the browser. Since it expects POST vars, you can simulate the AJAX environment by manually writing to the `$_POST` superglobal. Then, what do you see - errors?

Comment: Try it without explicitly serializing the data, too: jQuery converts it for you, so serializing it beforehand might not be ideal, try doing `var_dump($_POST);exit();` in your script, and check the response in Firebug to see what the dump looks like

Comment: Add an `error` handler and let jQuery tell you what went wrong - [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @Utkanos - if I manually declare the variables in the PHP file, it works.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - I used this, but am still getting null.  var login = $('#login').text();
 var password = $('#password').text();
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'Scripts/php/login.php',
   data: {login:login, password:password},

Comment: @Andreas, how do you use an error handler? I'm sorry, I am fairly new to jQuery.

Comment: @JasonT.Bedell - definitely sounds like there's a difference between the vars being sent and those you specify manually. Try this: in your PHP script, do a var-dump of the incoming `$_POST` superglobal into a text file, via `file_put_contents`, and see what turns up. This is a good way of debugging silent (i.e. AJAX) loads.

Comment: @Utkanos Thanks. I didn't know about that. That will be really helpful.

Comment: Really weird. I can get the true or false values by echoing with php. ie. echo $output; works but echo json_encode($output); does not. It seems like when I use json_encode, it isn't being sent back to the script. Is that possible?

Comment: `json_encode()` works only on an array - is that what you're feeding it?

Comment: @JasonT.Bedell Therefor I've linked the documentation ;) It's the same as the `success` handler, but with three parameters. `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }`

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `.text();` to `.val()` as `text()` gives blank result for text input types. `val()` will give actual value. Secondly use `var_dump($_POST); die;`. Ahh...check whether your function:

```
$('#loginForm #loginButton').click(function(){
        var $form = $('#loginForm'),
    $inputs = $form.find("input"),
    serializedData = $form.serialize();
    var login = $('#login').text('');
    var password = $('#password').text('');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Scripts/php/login.php',
      data: serializedData,
      success: function(response){
        console.log("Response: "+response);
        if(response != "false") 
        {
        //window.location.href='toolstart.html';
        $.cookie('lastname', response.lastname, { expires: 365, path: '/' });
        } else {
        alert("Your email and password combination did not match.");
        }

        },      
  dataType: 'json'
});**});**
```

is missing some curly braces, as I found. Do respond with your `var_dump($_POST);die;` message.

Comment: I thought it might be curly braces too, but they're ok. var_dump($_POST); gave me array(2) {
  ["login"]=>
  string(22) "jasontbedell@gmail.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}

Answer (score 0):

After several days, I did a little more research. It turns out, the server my client is using, only supports up to PHP 5.1 and json_encode is only supported in 5.1. Found this awesome script to make it work. http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

Thanks for all the help.